# How can I dock/anchor two listviews vertically aligned to grow equally on orientation change?

Tags: c#, listview, compact-framework

I have two ListViews in **Compact Framework 2.0** positioned vertically next to each other. Each of the ListViews occupies half of the screen. How can I dock/anchor them so when the orientation changes for landscape they grow equally and do not overlap each other.

From

```
-------- --------
|      | |      |    
|      | |      |    
|      | |      |    
-------- --------
```

Into

```
--------------  -------------
|            | |            |    
|            | |            |    
|            | |            |    
--------------  -------------
```

Comment: what is your platform? winforms? silverlight? wpf? the answer you get that solves your problem depends on this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(WinForms) Put them in 2 cells of a TableLayoutPanel. Set the Column-Widths to 50% each.

(After the) Edit: CF does not support this, use the ReSize event of the Form or containing Panel to do it yourself.